# How can I automatically delete all emails on a Gmail account the moment they arrive or are sent?

Tags: gmail

How can I automatically delete all emails on a Gmail account the moment they arrive or are sent?

Answer (score 3):

Add filter:

- In the search box click the down arrow.
- Enter `*`
- At the bottom of the search window, click Create filter with this search.
- Select Delete
- Create filter.

Comment: Great, this sends them all to the trash. But how to automatically delete them from the trash also ? I just have one more problem, the mail doesn't actually even get sent before getting deleted :/ How to prevent that ?

Comment: Not possible via web GUI. Wait 30 days or remove manually.

Comment: The mail was actually sent. There was a strange delay. Hmmm, is there no way I could code an auto-trash deleter ?

Comment: Possibly, but that would be beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter. I would go with `Does not have the words:` and input something cryptic here. This will cover all incoming mails.

Then you need something for the outgoing. Here, I would search for the name of the gmail account.

Then there is an option to delete all messages to which the filter applies.